# Scope in MATLAB vs R

Tags: r, matlab

I am learning to program in MATLAB, and have some experience in R. I am confused by the nature of scope in MATLAB.

```
y <- 1
test <- function(x) {
  return(x+y)
}
test(1)
```

in R, this returns a value of 2. R checks outside of the function for a value of y, when y is not passed as an input. However, in MATLAB,

```
function[ output ] = test(x)
output=x+y;

y=1;
test(1)
```

gives the error

```
Undefined function or variable 'y'
```

Can anyone explain the logic behind why scope behaves differently in MATLAB than I, a programmer in R, would expect it to work?

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/check-variable-scope-in-editor.html

Comment: There isn't logic, it's how the language was designed. There should be no expectation that scoping is the same between different programming languages. If that's valid R syntax then it's unlike most other languages. Scoping that broadly seems like a pretty poor idea TBH.

Comment: I see. You always draw expectations from the first language you learned, but good to know this is not the norm. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In matlab you have specify if the variable is `global`. You can do something like this:

```
function[ output ] = test(x)
    global y;
    output=x+y;
end
```

and then call the function:

```
global y;
y = 1;
test(1)
```

---

As far as I know this is not very common way of doing things in Matlab and Iwould advice against it. Instead you should just pass all variable to the function.

```
function[ output ] = test(x,y)
    output=x+y;
end
```

and then call the function:

```
y = 1;
test(1,y)
```

Comment: @ElliotLee Please note that I added a suggestion of an alternative way to accomplish the same thing.